# "File `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/checksum_cache.rb' not available" when trying to upload a cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, checksum

After having a fairly stable chef installation for I don't know how long, this has started popping up when trying to upload our deploy cookbook, after making a very simple change to it (changing an IP address attribute string to another IP address).

After hopping onto the chef server, indeed `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/checksum_cache.rb' isn't available, as it's not there.  I've done a fair bit of googling around for 'checksum_cache.rb' and 'Chef::ChecksumCache' but have come up with near enough no proper information, nor how to solve it.

Standard chef installation on a Ubuntu EC2 box, running

```
chef-server --version
```

gives me

```
Chef Server (API) Version: 10.18.2
```

Any help is extremely appreciated as this is obviously completely blocking our auto deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize from IRC, the file just needed to be restored manually from a copy of the package. Possibly disk corruption at work.

Also for the record, the distro packages for Chef and Chef Server should *never* be used.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously have a fairly broken configuration which will be replaced with a much more proper setup when it can, but for this *exact* problem, the solution was to restore the files from the deb package available.  Something quite wrong has obviously gone on on the server.